# Javascript load event on injected html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

If I inject html (iframe containing a video) through javascript is there an event/function that can be used to see if the injected HTML is finished loading?

I tried including javascript at the bottom of the injected content but that is not being executed.

Also I do not plan on using jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content is from **another domain**, all you can capture is the `onload` event for the `iframe` itself. That doesn't tell you the content has rendered, just that it has loaded.

Comment: same domain - took awhile but we fixed that problem

Answer (score 1):

After you inject the html, you could subscribe to the iframe's onload event:

```
document.getElementById("iframeId").onload = function(){
    alert("Loaded!");
};
```